# Is it better to set the default MYSQL JSON value to `{}` or `NULL`

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

We are starting to use the MySQL json datatype. Is there any recommended best practices when storing default values as `NULL` or `{}` for the JSON datatype? What are the PROs and CONs for each?

Comment: These do not have the same meaning, so it depends on your business requirements.

Answer (score 5):

This would depend upon your business use-case.

- `null` is usually meant to indicate that the value is unknown/doesn't
  exists.
- `{}` on the other hand means that the value is known/does
  exist and the known value is an empty JSON object `{}`

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that MySQL did not allow non-null default values for JSON columns prior to version 8.0.13 (released on 22/10/2018), according to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html):

> Prior to MySQL 8.0.13, a JSON column cannot have a non-NULL default value.

If you try it on a previous version you get an error:

`BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'column_name' can't have a default value`

So if backwards compatibility is a requirement, this is a con for `{}`.

Answer (score 1):

PhpMyAdmin uses the text `null` by default, if you add a new JSON column to existing rows.

Note this is different from *`NULL`*. *`NULL`* means unknown/doesn't exist in the database, `null` means unknown/doesn't exist after converted to JSON. `{}` is an empty JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

[42000][1101] BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'xxxx' can't have a default value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).